# what does the X[y==0,1] operation do here in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In this code:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, random_state=123)
plt.scatter(X[y==0,0], X[y==0,1], color='red', marker='^', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(X[y==1,0], X[y==1,1], color='blue', marker='o', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

What exactly does the operation `X[y==0,0]` do to the dataset `X`?

Comment: get the rows where y==0 and then get the 1st  element of those rows

Comment: That depends on the type of `X`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, both the variables `X` and `y` are of type numpy.ndarray.

And looking at the variables we can see that the variable `X` has shape (100, 2). This means that `X` has 100 rows and 2 columns. Similarly, `y` has shape (100,) and is thus just a 1-D vector. It happens to hold only 0s and 1s.

Thus `X[y==0,0]` finds all the rows of X that have a `y` value of 0 (`y == 0`), and are in the first column of `X`

Comment: "all the rows of X that have a y value of 0" would it maybe be clearer to say "all the rows of X where **the corresponding row of y** is equal to 0"?

Answer (score -1):

(X[y==0,0], X[y==0,1]) explaination:

X[y==0,0]

'y==0', This puts a condition that wherever y is 0. i.e only take those instances where y is 0

',0'  , This is element of X at index 0 in a list or X[0]

X[y==0,0], This whole expression is the x co-ordinate and it says, 'Only in those lists where y is 0(ignore rest of the lists), take X[0] as x-coodinate.

X[y==0,1], This whole expression is the y co-ordinate and it says, 'Only in those lists where y is 0(ignore rest of the lists), take X[1] as y-coodinate.

(X[y==0,0], X[y==0,1]), This whole expression is the x and y cordinates of a point in the scatterplot